# Proof that all Cauchy sequences converge by first principles?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

I'd like to prove that all Cauchy sequences of real numbers converge to a real number by invoking only the definition of a limit, and the definition of a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: You can’t. There are metric spaces where cauchy sequences need not be convergent. You should use some more additional information from the structure of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: It's crucial that the sequence is a sequence of **real numbers** .

Comment: Assuming that the terms of the sequence are real numbers (or complex numbers) you can do this in two steps. First show that a Cauchy sequence is bounded and hence has a limit point (via Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem). Next show that a Cauchy sequence can't have two distinct limit points. So there is only one limit point and the sequence converges to it.

Comment: Also note that the result you seek to prove is an equivalent formulation of the completeness property of real numbers and hence is a non-trivial result. Any efforts to prove this just using definition of limit and Cauchy sequence will not work. You need to invoke completeness of real numbers somewhere (like my previous comment mentions Bolzano-Weierstrass which is another formulation of completeness of real numbers).